# Fixed image overlapping another div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have different sections on a page. I then have an image fixed under these sections. I then have a large margin on my last section so when the user is scrolling down they will see the image and it will give it a 3d sort of effect. My issue is that my `#vanishing-text-container` div is not showing up over the image. I am unsure why as I have added a `z-index` of 1, which is higher than the image.

Does anyone see why my `#vanishing-text-container` div is not showing over the image?

```css
#safety-boxes, #scrolling-content, #safety-content {
 width: 100%;
}
/*---Safety Boxes----*/
#safety-boxes {
 /*height: 400px;*/
 height: 50%;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
#safety-box-large, .safety-box-small {
 vertical-align: top;
}
#safety-box-large {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #FF2F2F;
}
.safety-box-small {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}
#safety-box2 {
 background: #3e745b;
}
#safety-box3 {
 background: #6f9697;
}
.safety-box-icon {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 80px 0 60px 0;
}
.safety-box-title {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.5em;
 font-family: 'open_sanslight', "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 5px 8px;
}

/*----Vanishing Text ---*/

#vanishing-text-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 background: #FFF;
 z-index: 1;
}
#vanishing-text {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 150px;
 font-size: 3em;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 text-align: center;
}
/*---Scrolling Section---*/
#scrolling-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
   /* background: green;*/
 height: 400px;
}
#scrolling-content-container {
 padding-top: 150px;
 width: 100%;
}
#safety-main-img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#scrolling-content-description {
 text-align: center;
 /*position: absolute;
 top: 80%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
 font-size: 3em;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #FFF;
}

/*---Safety Content ---*/
#safety-content {
 margin-top: 300px;
 background: #EDEDED;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
#safety-content-container {
 padding: 100px 15%;
}

#safety-content-description {
 font-size: 1.5em
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="safety-boxes">
   <div id="safety-box-large">
    <img src="images/safety/head-protection.png" class="safety-box-icon" alt="Demolition and Wrecking Safety">
    <div class="safety-box-title">Safety is a top priority</div>
   </div><div class="safety-box-small" id="safety-box2">
    <img src="images/safety/shield.png" class="safety-box-icon" alt="The Eslich Wrecking Company Safety">
    <div class="safety-box-title">Safety Training</div>
   </div><div class="safety-box-small" id="safety-box3">
    <img src="images/safety/wrench.png" class="safety-box-icon" alt="Demolition and Wrecking Company Safety">
    <div class="safety-box-title">Right tools for the job</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="vanishing-text-container">
   <div id="vanishing-text">THE COMPANY PUTS SAFETY FIRST</div>
  </div>
  <div id="scrolling-content">
   <div id="scrolling-content-container">
    <!-- <div id="scrolling-content-description">WE CARE ABOUT THE SAFETY AND WELL BEING OF ALL LIVES</div> -->
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/eslich/images/safety/safety-main.jpg" alt="The Eslich Wrecking Company Promotes Safety Demolition" id="safety-main-img">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="safety-content">
   <div id="safety-content-container">
    <div id="safety-content-description">Safety</div>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, your image is in the scrolling-content div

Comment: @Keith My apologies, I entered the wrong div name. This div `vanishing-text-container` needs to go over the scrolling content div. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some sort of position on the #vanishing-text-container. Without a position, z-index won't work.

## vanishing-text-container { position: relative; }

This should fix it.